# How can i assignment some data to a typedef struct array?

Tags: c, struct

i want assignment a string to array of char in typedef struct like this

```
typedef struct convert{
char *upcase;
char *lowcase;
int number;
int order;
} convert;
convert sandi[27];
sandi[].upcase = {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"};
```

but it cannot

Comment: You can assign a string to an array element: `sandi[0].upcase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";` here the address of a string.

Comment: sandi is an array of structures; you must specify exactly which element in the array is initialized: sandi[#].upcase.

Comment: so if i want to assign all of the element, i must assign 1 by 1?

Comment: _i want assignment a string to array of char_ Note that you don't have any character arrays, only pointers to char.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A typedef declaration does not declare an object and in C you may not provide default values for members of a structure.

In such a case you need to use a loop as for example

```
typedef struct convert{
char *upcase;
char *lowcase;
int number;
int order;
} convert;

convert sandi[27];

char *upcase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 27; i++ )
{    
    sandi[i].upcase = upcase;
}
```